# Parâmetros em atributo Static

Tags: java, static

Tenho os seguintes atributos na minha classe:

```
static String URL="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://blablabla; databaseName=Pxx";    
static String usuario;  
static String password ;  
static String DRIVER="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
```

Gostaria de passar parâmetros para o atributo usuário e senha através de uma tela com 2 `inputs`:

```
<label>&nbsp;&nbsp; Usuário: <h:inputText value ="#{sql_controle.parans.usuario}"/></label>
    <label>&nbsp;&nbsp; Password: <h:inputText value ="#{sql_controle.parans.password}"/></label>
    <br></br><br></br>
    <p:commandButton value="CRIAR CONEXÂO" class ="btnSalvar" 
    action="#{sql_controle.createParam()}" onclick="#"/>
```

Só que elas não estão recebendo os parâmetros qualquer atributo de outra classe que utilizo esse procedimento não sendo `static` funciona. Gostaria de saber como fazer isso em atributos do tipo `static`.

Answer (score 0):

O JSF utiliza os getters e setters do Controller para transferir as informações da View para o Controller.
Não utilizamos getters e setters em membros staticos (talvez getters.. hehe)
Dessa forma, você deve criar algum método público que passe as informações para seus membros staticos.
Tent algo tipo assim:

```
public void passaValorUsuario(String usuario) {
    SuaClasse.usuario = usuario;
}
```

:-)